# are terminals full screen on windows 8?

Tags: windows, powershell

This is a pretty small thing, but I have been getting into more and more windows coding, and recently began finding myself in a terminal (msysgit, powershell). However, something that bugs the CRAP out of me is that there is no full screen modes, and they have to be resized

So my question:
For any windows 8 users, are terminals (msysgit, powershell, cmd) maximable / customizable at all?

I HAVE used console2 (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Console2ABetterWindowsCommandPrompt.aspx), but while it is resizable, it does not maximize.I am weighing if whether my next computer will be a mac or windows, and this info will be useful in making that decision. I am getting tired of crazy work-arounds to get simple things changed in windows.

Comment: Nobody codes in PowerShell, get an IDE or use Notepad (++ even better). But you can resize / customize PS, never tried to maximize though... That's a lot of precious real estate lost

Comment: Buy a Mac. In fact, buy any modern computer - and you'll find that the screen is so big that running a shell full-screen doesn't help - not even slightly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows doesn't really have "terminal" windows (except for those provided by a third party).  Windows has a console subsystem which PowerShell, cmd.exe and any other console program you write, run in.  The Windows console subsystem is old, hasn't changed much and is definitely showing its age.  While there is a maximize button on every console window, as you have no doubt noticed, it doesn't maximize the window to full screen.

For script editing, I would use PowerShell_ISE or Visual Studio with the PowerShell Tools for VS add-in.  To enable a number of BASH-like line editing features in PowerShell, you should check out [PSReadLine on GitHub](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine).  It makes using PowerShell much nicer.